# C++ Exception Handling and Enum Scoping

Tags: c++, exception, enums, enumeration

I wrote the following exception class:

```
class generic_exception : public std::exception
{

  public:

    generic_exception( std::string where, int err_code , bool fatal ) 
    : where_(where) , errcode_(err_code) ,fatal_(fatal) {}

      inline int get_errcode()
      {
        return errcode_;
      }

      inline bool is_fatal()
      {
        return (fatal_ == true ? true : false);
      }

      inline std::string get_where()
      {
        return where_;
      }

     ~generic_exception() throw () { }

  private:

    std::string where_;
    int errcode_;
    bool fatal_;

};
```

I used this for handling errors without creating one exception class for each type of error. All err_code values are essentialy enumerator values (all of those defined in in the single classes that need error checking) used as error codes.

some example class:

```
class A
{
  enum one{a,b,c}
};

class B
{
  enum two{d,e,f}
};
```

try catch example:

```
try
    {
      //something
      throw generic_exception("where" , one::a , true );
      throw generic_exception("where" , two::a , true );

    }
    catch( generic_exception e)
    {
      switch(e.get_errcode())
      {
        case one::a:
          break;
        case two::b:
          break;
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm having problems when two values from different enums but same integer value appear in the same switch case statement.
When this happens , like in the example above, the compiler prints an "error: duplicate case value". I guess that the cause of this error is 
attributable to the integer 'nature' of the two families.
How can i solve this problem? Am I obliged to change this "generic exception scheme " to polymorphic scheme (one exception class for single error type)?

Comment: If these error codes have to be unique, you will have to use one enumeration for these errorcodes or you will have to do the trick, that the second enumeration starts with the last value of your first enumeration increased by 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either:

**1)** Use global enumeration:

```
enum ErrorCode
{
    A_one,
    A_two,
    A_three,
    //...

    B_one,
    B_two,
    //...
};
```

**2)** Or use enumerators counting:

```
class A
{
public:
    enum
    {
        Err_one,
        Err_two,
        Err_three,
        //...

        Last_error
    };
};

class B
{
public:
    enum
    {
        Err_one = A::Last_error,
        Err_two,
        Err_three,
        //...

        Last_error
    };
};
```

Trick with `Last_error` is nice, because you can define many enums this way, and if you add/remove some enumerators, none of them will require updating. If you want to avoid defining additional enumerators, you should assign to first enumerator value of last enumerator in previous enum, increased by 1.

But note, that in this case even small change in enum defined in `A`  can require updating enum defined in class `B` (because different enumerator can become the last one after change).